# Como inserir vários valores digitados pelo usuário em dicionário em Java?

Tags: java, dicionário

Quero permitir que vários pares(chave, valor) sejam inseridos num dicionário, em Java, a partir de valores digitados pelo usuário. Fiz um laço `for` para tentar inserir, mas não consegui, pois toda vez que um novo par(chave, valor) é inserido, sobrescreve o anterior. É possível fazer isso? Permitir várias entradas nesse dicionário?

O código abaixo cria o dicionário `phoneBook` e adiciona, ou pelo menos tenta, novos pares, através da variáveis `name` e `phone`.

```
    Map<String, Integer> phoneBook = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    int i, phone = 0;
    String name = " ", phoneNumber = " ";

    int n = reading.nextInt(); // Quantidade de casos de teste
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        name = reading.next();
        phone = reading.nextInt();
        phoneBook.put(name, phone);
    }
```

Essa parte insere uma nova `String` que permitirá que uma pesquisa aconteça. Caso o valor seja encontrado, ele imprime, ou pelo menos deveria, os valores consultados pelo usuário:

```
    while(reading.hasNext()){

        String s = reading.next();

        if(phoneBook.containsKey(s)){
            System.out.println(s + "=" + phoneBook.get(name));  
        } else{
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
```

**Exemplos de entrada e saída**

Ele começa com a entrada de um número inteiro para o número de casos de testes, seguido das entradas do usuário, depois passa para a pesquisa. Se o valor for encontrado, ele é impresso. Se não for, uma mensagem com "Not Found" será exibida:

***Entrada***

```
3
Van 99995555
Fernando 11115555
Marilia 66668888
Van
Emilly
Marilia
```

***Saída Esperada:***

```
Van=99995555
Not Found
Marilia=66668888
```

Só que a saída não sai como esperado, ele sempre retorna o último número adicionado, quando a chave é encontrada no dicionário:

```
Van=66668888
Not Found
Fernando=66668888
```

Alguém pode me ajudar nisso?
Desde já, muito obrigada!

Comment: Oi Van, não seria o caso de você ler de voc receber o input da variável nome e da variável phone. Depois converter a variável phone para integer. Ai só usar o .put com as duas variáveis. Essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5287561/7755215) pode te ajudar .

Comment: Oi, @Davi Mello, eu não entendi o que você quis dizer,  a variável phone já do Integer. Meu está armazenar mais de um par(chave, valor) no phoneBook.

Comment: Tipo, se eu fosse inserir um par vez, eu teria que escrever: phoneBook.put("van", 33334444);. Mas quero inserir um número indefinido de vezes. Por exemplo, se usuário quiser inserir três vezes ou mais pares diferentes de uma vez: phoneBook.put("van", 33334444);/ phoneBook.put("marcos", 55556666);/ phoneBook.put("fernando", 88889999); É isso que quero fazer. O problema é que sempre que o usuário insere um novo par, sobrescreve o anterior.

Comment: O map só sobrescreve se você usar a mesma chave. Ex: se fizer `phoneBook.put("van", 33334444);` e depois `phoneBook.put("van", 99991111);`, ele vai sobrescrever o valor anterior porque a chave (`"van"`) é a mesma. Mas se as chaves forem diferentes (como no seu exemplo: `phoneBook.put("van", 33334444);/ phoneBook.put("marcos", 55556666);/ phoneBook.put("fernando", 88889999);`, nenhum deles é sobrescrito. Por favor, clique em **[edit]** e coloque alguns exemplos para deixar mais claro o que de fato está acontecendo, pois só com as informações passadas não está muito claro que é o problema.

Comment: Ok, @hkotsubo! Vou editar! Obrigada! 

Comment: No while, em vez de `System.out.println(s + "=" + phoneBook.get(name))`, faça `System.out.println(s + "=" + phoneBook.get(s))`

Comment: @hkotsubo deu certo, muito obrigada! ^_^